# Regex optional group not working

Tags: regex, html-parsing

At the moment I'm learning regular expressions and there are many thing I don't understand.

I have a website with a table, where I want to extract the items. One of the columns can contain either a fix value (in this example "foo") or nothing, the other columns contain always some data. The extraction of them works good, but the optional content in the special column does not. Therefore i use a expression like

```
<a id=x .*?>(.*?)</a>.*?<a id=y .*?>(.*?)</a>
```

My actual problem is the following part of the final expression

```
...   .*?(foo)?.*?   ...
```

which should achieve that between the other cells there is a cell with content foo, which can miss and should only returned if its there. What am I doing wrong? Some basical understanding?

Comment: Learning is great, but regex isn't the right tool for pulling data out of html.

Comment: What are good way to extract data from websites? Regex seemed to be very flexible and fun :)

Comment: [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Ok thank you, i will have a look at this, but my question is also interesting for me related to regex, because I don't understand the behaviour in this case.

Comment: Since `foo` is not necessary to be there, the `.*?` can match whatever it wants to match, then skip over if `foo` does not exist in the current position in the string.

Comment: Some interesting comparison: http://www.regex101.com/r/iL4rI8 vs http://www.regex101.com/r/oX3lO1

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/ for examples of how to properly parse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the regex `.*?(foo)?.*?`, since `foo` is optional, the regex engine will just look at the current position in the text. If `foo` is there, it will be included in the match; otherwise, it will just skip over without checking that there isn't any `foo` at all.

You can change the behavior a bit by modifying the regex to `(.*?foo|.*?).*?`. The regex will try its best to find the next `foo`. Unless the string ahead doesn't contain `foo`, the regex above will definitely consume `foo`. In [regex-directed engine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html), the alternation `|` is not fair, and the regex engine in this case will its best to match the one specified in front before trying the next one, and if it matches anything then it will continue on (unless there is something ahead that doesn't match then it will turn back and backtrack).

Note that what I demonstrated above is more than likely **not** a solution. You should look in the data to see if there is any good feature to limit on how the characters are consumed, so that you can differentiate between the matches.